# How do I turn off mouse acceleration in Skyrim?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mouse

Mouse acceleration seems to be on by default, and I can't find anywhere in the launcher settings or the in game settings to turn it off.

It's very annoying as it makes it feel as if the mouse is lagging. Is there any way to turn it off?

Comment: Related: [How can I sync vertical/horizontal mouse sensitivities?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34889/sync-vertical-horizontal-mouse-sensitivities)

Comment: If you shoot the skeever from stealth, that mouse won't be doing any acceleratin'!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Go to `\Users\[Username]\My Documents\My Games\Skyrim`
2. Open the `SkyrimPrefs.ini` file with notepad
3. Find the line `bMouseAcceleration=1` (located under `[Controls]`)
   (If there is no line, add it)
4. Replace the `1` with a `0`
5. Save the file (make sure you don't accidentally save it as `SkyrimPrefs.ini.txt`)

Comment: Now if I could just find how to syncs x/y sensitivities.

Comment: Also turning off Vsync seems to help mouse lag.

Comment: 2 things: Firstly, how do I turn off vsync, can't find it anywhere. Secondly, I've looked in both my skyrim.ini, and my skyrimprefs.ini and the "bMouseAcceleration=1" was in neither, and putting it in either myself (with a 0 instead of 1) didn't fix anything.

Comment: @MrSmooth: To disable VSync add "iPresentInterval=0" to the bottom of the [Display] section in Skyrim.ini
bMouseAcceleration should be in the SkyrimPrefs.ini under the [Controls] heading. Editing answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ok it wasn't there, but I added it there, and now mouse acceleration is off (don't know whether it was the vsync though, but whatever).

Comment: I couldn't find "bMouseAcceleration"...
is it about Xbox360 controller?

Comment: @Sardun bMouseAcceleration is about a computer mouse. If you don't see bMouseAcceleration, then add it under [Controls].

Comment: there is a folder in the steam files as well as my documents, which should I edit? I did both, but is it necessary or does one override the other?

Comment: I added "bMouseAcceleration" under [Controls] but it still doesn't fix it.
Though "iPresentInterval=0" did fix this problem in the menus, the mouse delay persists.