# How can I sync vertical/horizontal mouse sensitivities?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mouse

Is there a way to tweak Skyrim so that vertical cursor sensitivity = horizontal cursor sensitivity?

Comment: Related: [How do I turn off mouse acceleration in Skyrim?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34878/how-do-i-turn-off-mouse-acceleration-in-skyrim).

Comment: I know you answered that one, Arkive, but it should be useful for people who find this question.  As a side note, have you tried adjusting the sensitivities in Windows to compensate?  I realize that changing them back and forth just to play the game may be annoying.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Under [controls] in Skyrim.ini (Found in "My Documents\My Games\Skyrim") there are two entries.

```
fMouseHeadingYScale=0.0100
fMouseHeadingXScale=0.0200
```

Change the YScale to match the XScale and all is well in the world again.

Comment: I didn't have those entries or a [controls] section, but adding them worked. Thanks!

Comment: What a strange default

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the best solution but it works for me until I find a better way.

I don't have the entries `fMouseHeadingYScale` and `fMouseHeadingXScale` in my `skyrimprefs.ini`.

I tried code's solution (messing with fov) and it didn't work either. So for now I only changed the aspect ratio standard to 4:3 or 5:4 in the options on the launcher. It's gonna be liveable until a better way is found.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have entries for fMouseHeadingXScale then just add them. I set them both at 0.0100 and now everything is working much better.

The interface is still not perfect but the mouse seems to be working properly and the game is playable (to my standards at least) now.

Answer (score 1):

A full solution is presented here :

If it's not enough, (like for me: old sys = low framerate + a widescreen), play windowed in 4/3.

A patch is coming at the end of november, maybe it'll provide a real solution.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.