# How to increase mouse sensitivity in Skyrim?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mouse

How can i increase mouse sensitivity in Skyrim?

- on the main menu the mouse cursor is sluggish
- in-game mouse sensitivity is too low

---

Things i've tried:

- increasing **Look Sensitivity** in-game:

  [image]
- In my `SkyrimPrefs.ini` file:

  - Increasing `[Controls]\fMouseHeadingSensitivity` from `0.0125` to `1.0500`
  - Adding `[Controls]\fMouseHeadingXScale` = `1.0500`
  - Adding `[Controls]\fMouseHeadingYScale` = `1.0500`
  - Turning off mouse acceleration: Changing `[Controls]\bMouseAcceleration` from `1` to `0`
  - Turning off v-sync: Adding `[Display]\iPresentInterval` = `0`
- Changing **Detail** in the launcher to **Low** from auto-detected **Ultra**
  [image]
- Running in Windowed mode
  [image]
- Turning off Steam's Overlay UI:
  [image]
- Increasing my mouse pointer speed in Windows
  [image]

**Note:** My question is different from [How can I sync vertical/horizontal mouse sensitivities?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34889/how-can-i-sync-vertical-horizontal-mouse-sensitivities), which looks to make the poor mouse sensitivity equal in both directions. i want *not* poor mouse sensitivity.

**Note**: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\skyrim\Skyrim\SkyrimPrefs.ini"`

**Note**: And restarting Skyrim after each change.

**Note**: Including details of what i've tried are only presented to shut people up who bitch about a "lack of research effort". i *should* be able to ask my question with explanation, justification, or research. Also people love screenshots - it draws them in like moths.

### See also

- [FoV and sensitivity.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/60954909)
- [How do I even out the mouse sensitivity?](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/60961771)
- [Tweaks to make Skyrim that much better (self.skyrim)](http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/m7zja/tweaks_to_make_skyrim_that_much_better/)

Comment: This question is relevant to my interests. I did all of this, as well as turning off mouse acceleration. The DPI on my G500 is maxed out at 2500 right now, and it still requires a ton of arm movement and lifting up the mouse just to turn around. :( Have you tried capping the framerate at 30fps? I've heard that worked for some people. I'm trying to find the method and I'll update this post when I do.

Comment: did you try to increase cursor speed in you (OS) config panel?

Comment: I need to know the opposite myself. When in the menu, the mouse is too sensitive and I've tried adjusting mouse sensitivity via control panel.

Comment: Heads-up: [Disabling Vsync is HIGHLY UNRECOMMENDED. It introduces bugs with physics, time-scaling, graphics and controls](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/103571/4797)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [suggested](http://booncontrol.com/threads/skyrim-ini-tweaks-and-general-troubleshooting.2316/) `SkyrimPrefs.ini` i was using was the wrong one.

Using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) i was able to figure out that the correct one is:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\SkyrimPrefs.ini
```

e.g.

```
C:\Users\Ian\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\SkyrimPrefs.ini
```

[image]

Changing `[Controls]\fMouseHeadingSensitivity` to

```
fMouseHeadingSensitivity=0.1250  (new)
fMouseHeadingSensitivity=0.0125  (old)
```

did the trick.

Comment: Perfect information!!

Comment: This worked great for me in game. In the main menu the mouse is still TERRIBLY slow. Any ideas on how I might fix it?

Comment: @dborba There i cannot help you; i feel your pain.

Comment: I was having this issue and thought I was going crazy when after a day of playing I'd tried most of the things documented in your question, even changed my wireless mouse batteries, and nothing worked. My existing value was `fMouseHeadingSensitivity=0.0500`, I think, but the new value you suggest still worked well for me. Thank you so much for the clear writeup. (I found the post from Google when I wasn't logged in while gaming, and it was a huge help.)

Comment: @aediaλ In the SkyrimPrefs.ini file, under [Interface] there is the line: `fMouseCursorSpeed=1.0000` Change that value to whatever you want, and ta da! Your mouse should be faster in the menus!