# How to fix Skyrim's incredibly long loading screen caused by d3d9.dll?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues, framerate

I have just bought Skyrim, and instead of 3 hours of playing, I've been spending 3 hours getting it to work. I experienced heavy mouse input lag (about 0.2 seconds, try to block someone's sword with that). I fixed this problem using instructions in [this video](https://youtu.be/g2AJDJ8sOfQ).

In particular, this instruction had the strongest effect:

> Step 6:
>   -download "D3D_Antilag_v1.1" and move "D3D9.dll" and
>   "antilag.cfg" into the game folder (where the *.exe files are located)
>   -open antilag.cfg with notepad and set "frames rendered ahead" to "1" (This forces frames rendered ahead to 1 and adds a framelimiter, which
>   is required to fix vertical sensitivity issues)
>
> Step 7:
>   -open antilag.cfg with notepad and change "FPSlimit" to "50"

<sup>I downloaded it from here: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/34/</sup>

However, as long as `D3D9.dll` file is present, game takes up to 7 minutes to load the main wasteland area and up to minute to load when you enter/leave a building. I found two workarounds:

1. Ctrl+Alt+Delete out of the game, when you focus the game again, the game will instantly

   - 70% finish loading
   - 30% crash
2. Read a book during loading. So far the only reliable workaround.

Is there a way to prevent this long loading problem? I have a strong suspicion it has something to do with FPS limiter, since exiting the rendering mode allows for instant load (if it doesn't crash, that is).

Renaming the DLL file to `D3D9.dll.bak` instantly removes the long loading and instantly re-adds the input lag, so this file is relevant to both problems. The game is unplayable with mouse input lag since I can hardly aim for inventory items and people. This means I desperately need to get the FPS limiter to work, otherwise I just wasted 15€ for nothing.

How to I resolve the long loading without removing the FPS limiter?

Comment: Are your computer's stats at or above what Skyrim requires? There may be only so much you can do.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Well since the DLL file magically fixes my problems without reducing game graphics quality, I doubt stats are directly related. Surely, with fast enough CPU this wouldn't happen.

Comment: It might be better to ask how to fix your input lag (be sure to list what you've already tried), since that seems to be the root issue you're having.

Comment: @Xantec It's all in the question already. Did you finish the first paragraph, which directly links to video that solved the input lag?

Answer (score 1):

The mouse lag can be caused by display driver problems.

Try updating your graphics card drivers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **try installing [SKSE](http://skse.silverlock.org/)** and see what effect it has. You can try [tweaking its settings](https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/540740500921363665/) if you feel up for it.

As for the `d3d9.dll` issue, I suggest you **try a version of [ENB](http://enbdev.com/download_mod_tesskyrim.html)**, since the 'Wrapper Version' will replace the existing `d3d9.dll`.

If this reintroduces your mouse lag problems, you might want to try **some alternative methods to fix the input lag**:

- Change the `Max Frames to Render Ahead` in the NVIDIA Control Panel to *1*, preferably, or *0*. 

  If you have an ATI video card, the process is a little harder, since the similar `Flip Queue Size` option was removed years ago. You can add this through the Windows Registry Editor. Go to:

  > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\
  > Class
  >   {4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000\UMD

  Add a Binary Value called "FlipQueueSize", and set its value to *31 00*.

  (More on that [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/3b1qdg/flip_queue_size_1_without_radeon_pro/?st=iu7fup4l&sh=d155dd3e), and some general insightful info [here](https://community.amd.com/thread/180170)).
- Install the [Borderless Window mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/36177/).
- Another suggestion can be found in the approved solution [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35226/how-can-i-fix-mouse-lag-in-skyrim) on the Arqade.

---

Alternatively, if only keeping your `d3d9.dll` file present in the game folder prevents mouse lag, there are **some additional tips that might help cutting down loading times**:

- Delete or move as many saved games as possible from the default location:

  > C:\Users\*'username'*\My Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves\

  This will prevent the game from loading their thumbnails and some extra info (player name, play duration, location).
- Skyrim - especially when modded with script-adding and -altering mods - has the tendency to exponentially increase the size of its saved games. When this is the case a saved game cleaner can do wonders for loading times. There are several, so I'll name a few: [Skyrim Save Cleaner](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31724), [FallrimTools ReSaver](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/5031/), and the [Save game script cleaner](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/52363/) . Download and install any of them, and follow the steps mentioned on their respective Nexus page.
- Changing the *fps* setting might [help](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/676535-long-load-times-in-skyrim-fix/), either by capping at different values or uncapping it. For some users in the linked thread, setting it at 35 has made loading times up to 4 times faster. Some ENB's have caps built in, but you can also change the values through your video card utility software (e.g. Catalyst Control Center or NVIDIA Control Panel).