# Why can't I turn off mouse acceleration in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mouse

I've looked at this thread already: [How do I turn off mouse acceleration in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34878/how-do-i-turn-off-mouse-acceleration-in-skyrim)

However, I've tried it and it doesn't seem to turn of mouse acceleration. **I have already tried to change 'bMouseAcceleration' to equal 0.** I've also tried entering in iPresentInteval=0 to turn off VSync or something... Do I need to somehow refresh Skyrim on Steam or something? I didn't change the name of the file, for anyone who's wondering. Thanks in advance.

Also, if this helps, I have an MSI GE62 6QD with:
16 GB ram
i7-6700HQ @ 2.60 GHz
Nvidia GTX960m 2 GB

P.S. I know it isn't working because the mouse cursor does not follow the in-game cursor, and it still feels "floaty".

Comment: As I've said, I have already looked at that thread. It is not working for me.

Comment: How do you know it's not working?  You haven't given any info on that at all, just that it seems like not.  Either way, though, the question's already been asked; we don't allow questions asking the same things.

Comment: I know because the mouse acceleration is still on in-game... (i.e. the cursor still has the "floaty" feeling). I also had the double cursor for a while, and tested by seeing if the in-game cursor followed my real cursor 1:1. It did not. I don't see how this question has been asked, since the original thread did not answer my question.

Comment: Support questions where a previous solution didn't work for them are asked all the time. Especially when they take the time to link the question that didn't work for them.

Comment: Right, I understand that, but I'm not saying that these types of question have been not asked before, but this particular question.

Comment: @JamesLeung my comment was directed towards Frank. I think that your question should not be considered a duplicate since the "other question" didn't help your situation. This has to be the case if we are to allow "tech support" questions at all.. it's not a one-solution-for-all type thing.

Comment: @TimS. Ah, I see. Sorry for my confusion. I got mixed up in the comment system.

Comment: By any chance do you have the acceleration problem with any other game? I assume you restarted Skyrim? Perhaps try closing the game, and logging out of steam, logging back in and see if the value you changed is still 0. If not, Steam's auto-update feature may need disabled.

Comment: I re-logged and it is still 0. I checked in-game as well, and it still is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions [from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/m7zja/tweaks_to_make_skyrim_that_much_better) about this issue (note one of them you already tried):

Borrowed from "Dead man posting" on the Something awful forums, All credit goes to him. Reposted here for Reddits pleasure:

How do I fix the crash to desktop?

```
Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Sound
In the Playback tab, right click on Speakers (or whatever has a green tick next to it), then click Properties
In the advanced tab on this new window, select 24 bit, 44100Hz (Studio Quality) in the drop down menu
```

How do I fix some sound issues, such as hearing static during NPC dialogue?

```
Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Sound
In the Playback tab, right click on Speakers (or whatever has a green tick next to it), then click Properties
In the advanced tab on this new window, select 24 bit, 44100Hz (Studio Quality) in the drop down menu
```

How do I disable the smooth mouse settings?

```
Go to your Steam Directory -> steamapps -> common -> skyrim -> Skyrim
Create a backup of the SkyrimPrefs.ini file
Open the file, then scroll down to where it says [Controls] and find bMouseAcceleration=1
Change to bMouseAcceleration=0
Save, exit, and play
```

How do I fix the vsync ("laggy mouse") problem?

```
Go to your Steam Directory -> steamapps -> common -> skyrim -> Skyrim
Create a backup of the SkyrimPrefs.ini file
Open the file, then scroll down to where it says [Display]
Add to the bottom of the section iPresentInterval=0
Save, exit, and play
```

How do I change the FOV?

```
Go to your My Documents -> My Games -> Skyrim -> skyrim
Create a backup of the skyrim.ini file
Open the file, then scroll down to where it says [General]
At the bottom of this section, add fdefaultfov=XX (where XX is the FOV value you want to change to)
Save, exit, and play
```

EDIT: After much discussion in the thread, it would appear the above FOV command does not stick, and will revert to 70 on Fast-Travel. Try the console command "Fov xx" (~ for console, xx for an fov number)

Comment: If you're going to answer, we try to keep answers together in a single question.  That's the whole point of the duplicate system.

Comment: Since I disagree with the fact that this is a duplicate (few tech support issues are) the point is moot. I'm sure you disagree, but I'm not trying to change your mind.

Comment: I've actually already looked at this post as well. I tried adding "iPresentInterval"  and, as you know, the mouse acceleration—both to no avail. I don't have any of the other problems. though.